# Is it possible in mathematica to use dynamic names of variables

Tags: programming, core-language, variable

I have variables in my code following the following notation :

theta12, theta13, theta14 etc..

I would check the values of all this variable so I could write an if condition for each theta but I wondered if it is possible to name the variables "dynamically", like if it was an array.

For example is it possible to write "thetakj" where k and j are integers on which I am looping on and mathematica understand this notation.

Am I forced to use an array to do it ?

Comment: Have a look at `Map`

Comment: `ToExpression["theta" <> ToString[k] <> ToString[j]]`?

Comment: Or consider using SubValues, e.g. define theta[1,3], theta[1,4], ...

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick These are still `DownValues` :)

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, I will look at your functions !

Comment: @halirutan, indeed so!

Comment: This is a fairly common question.  I marked it as "already has an answer" pointing to two that I remember but I'm sure there are more.  If anyone has a suggestion for other Q&A's to add to the header please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something similar to what you need I suppose?

```
Clear@theta;

$PreRead = ReplaceAll[#, RowBox[{"theta", seq_}] :>
     Block[{},
      Module[{myHold}, SetAttributes[myHold, HoldAllComplete]; 
        With[{preproc = myHold[theta] @@ (ToExpression[#, TraditionalForm, myHold] & /@ Characters@seq)},
         With[{inject = Hold[preproc] //. myHold[cont_] :> cont}, 
          ToBoxes[inject][[1, 3]]]]] /; True]] &;

$PrePrint = 
 ReplaceAll[#, 
   theta[seq__] :> 
    With[{expr = MakeExpression[ RowBox[{"theta", StringJoin[ToString /@ {seq}]}], TraditionalForm]},
     ReleaseHold@Defer@expr]] &;
```

---

## Usage

slightly different from what you wanted, but still very similar: just need a space between `theta` and those parameters:

e.g.

```
theta 12 = 3

theta 14 = 2;

theta 12 + theta 13

theta 12 + theta 14

(theta 12)*8

Table[theta ij,{i,4},{j,4}]

theta 12=.

Table[theta ij,{i,4},{j,4}]
```

---

## Notes

(and basic idea as well)

Do not assign values to `theta` as what's doing in dark is replacing all `theta ij` expressions to `theta[i,j]` and turn it back when showing to you!

Use `(theta ij)` when you cannot deternmine whether `theta ij` along can create correct answer.

*Acknoledge that `theta 14` means `theta[1,4]`, not `theta[14]`! thus `theta (2*3+2)` would return `theta 14` which means `theta[14]` while evaluate it again will result in `theta[1,4]`!*

---

## Improvements

```
Clear@theta;

$PrePrint = 
  ReplaceAll[#, 
    theta[seq__] :> 
     With[{expr = 
        MakeExpression[
         RowBox[{"theta", Sequence @@ (ToString /@ {seq})}], 
         TraditionalForm]}, ReleaseHold@Defer@expr]] &;

$PreRead = ReplaceAll[#, RowBox[{"theta", seq__}] :>
     Block[{},
      Module[{myHold}, SetAttributes[myHold, HoldAllComplete]; 
        With[{preproc = 
           myHold[theta] @@ 
            ToExpression[{seq}, TraditionalForm, myHold]},
         With[{inject = Hold[preproc] //. myHold[cont_] :> cont}, 
          ToBoxes[inject][[1, 3]]]]] /; True]] &;
```

in this case, write `theta i j k` instead of `theta ijk` would be okay. It would cause less confusion with stuffs like `theta 14`.

A small note: in the output form, `theta 1 2 1` or so will be displayed as `theta 2` while the fullform keep honest. so just pay more attention to `1`s, and everything would be okay.